# How do you render data stored on mlab onto a React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mlab

For instance if I have a User schema and I want to render a dynamic list of the property "name" for each user already stored in mlab how would I go about doing so? If you could point me to a tutorial that would be great as well.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `mongodb driver` or `mongoose`. I recommend using `mongoose`
as it makes it much easier to connect to your mongo database.

After you've created a db on your mlab account, just copy the `Mongodb URI` and format it like so:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dsXXXXX.mlab.com:XXXXX/test-app // XXXXX is the port number given to you by mlab
```

According to [Mongoose Official Documentations](http://mongoosejs.com/):

// App.js (component)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('your-mlab-mongodb-uri'); // insert your mlab `MongoDb URI`

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { cats: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      Cat.find({}).then(function(result) {
          this.setState({ cats: result });
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { cats } = this.state;
      if (cats && cats.length > 0) {
          return (
           <div>
             {
               cats.map((cat, index) =>(
                   <p key={index}>{cat.name}</p>
               ))
             }
           </div>
          );
       }

      return <h1>Loading data..</h1>
  }
}
```

And I suggest using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) - there are a lot of tutorials about that - to process the data to and from your database. In the example above, I'm directly retrieving the data from the component for sake of giving a simple example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, this is the part I already know how to do and my info's already being saved on mlab. I actually need to see how to do the get from mLab + render part.